# JPA Many to Many with Intermediate Table and MapKey*

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1

I'm struggling to setup the following JPA mapping (extra cols, etc. omitted for brevity)

```
----
id: primary key


organization
------------
id: primary key
z

role_assignment
---------------
role_assignment_id: primary key
user_id: fk -> user.id
organization_id: fk -> organization.id
role

(user_id, organization_id) is unique
```

The mapping needed would be on `Organization` class:

`Map<User, RoleAssignment> roleAssignments`

I can get close with something like:

```java
class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;
}

class RoleAssignment {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "role_assignment_id")
  private long id;

  @Column(name = "role")
  private String role;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  private User user;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "organization_id")
  private Organization organization;
}

class Organization {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @MapKey(name = "user")
  private Map<User, RoleAssignment> roleAssignments;
}
```

I've tried several configurations with MapKey, MapKeyJoinColumn, etc, and the best I get is a map with one null key mapped to a single value (despite multiple entries in the database).

Any help on setting this up would be greatly appreciated.

## Update

I think I omitted some key info trying to be concise. The following paints a more clear picture:

```
----
id: primary key


organization
------------
id: primary key


role
----
id: primary key


role_assignment
---------------
role_assignment_id: primary key
user_id: fk -> user.id
organization_id: fk -> organization.id
role_id: fk -> role

(user_id, organization_id) is unique and can be made primary key if needed
```

The mapping needed would be on `Organization` class:

`Map<User, RoleAssignment> roleAssignments`

I can get close with something like:

```java
class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;
}

class RoleAssignment {
  // this could be converted to an @EmbeddedId if that helps
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "role_assignment_id")
  private long id;

  @Column(name = "role")
  private String role;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  private User user;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "organization_id")
  private Organization organization;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
  private Role role;
}

class Organization {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "organization", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @MapKey(name = "user") // <-- this is the piece I can't get to work
  private Map<User, RoleAssignment> roleAssignments;
}
```

I'm able to get a basic mapping to `List<RoleAssignment>` to work, but the logic of the rest of the application requires the `Map` mapping I described.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many

Comment: @Zorglube I'm able to setup a mapping with basic collections, it's getting the `MapKey*` annotations to work to produce the result as a `Map` that I can't get

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many#many-to-many-using-a-composite-key <= here Organization is you composite key.

Comment: First, your onetoMany can't be mapped by user. Mapped by means that something on the other side, within RoleAssignment, contains the mapping back to this Entity (Organization). User points to a user, so isn't what you want, maybe try "organization". Next , remove the map and have it just as a List <RoleAssignment> and see if that works; it seems to match your table structure. Once that is working, you know then the issue is with your MapKey and you can try it again, though if you only need the role string, you might just use Map<User, String> with no need for a RoleAssignment entity

Comment: @Chris changing to 'organization' for mappedBy helped, thanks! I'm still not able to get the mapping to work as a `Map` though, see my edits above.